# How to scroll to specific item in ListView using triggers

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, multitrigger

I am new to triggers concepts and I'm not able to get the right approach as to how to achieve it.

Based on data I have to scroll. Suppose data is `cat` so in list I have to 'scroll to `cat`'.

```
<ViewCell Height="80">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding Data}" 
               TextColor="White" 
               FontSize="45" 
               Margin="10,5,0,0" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" 
                             Binding="{Binding Data}" 
                             Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Text" 
                            Value="{Binding Data}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your code, for example xaml page code where is your listview located, your viewmodel if you are using mvvm, etc.

Comment: @AlmirVuk My full page is a list.I am getting Data from api.I have many things in list view.I want to point to particular cell containing the Data value.

Comment: Suppose i have a list of 30 items in that 30 items if Data value is CAT then the list should scroll to Cat out of that 30 items

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments... You want to scroll to specific item in your `ListView`. First thing you need to have is a reference to that specific object in your `ItemSource` list, after that using `ScrollTo` method you can scroll to that specific list item in your `ListView`.

You can try implement that like this:

```
 // targetObjectInListView = reference to some list item which you want to scroll to.
 YourListView.ScrollTo(targetObjectInListView , ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
```

More about `ListView.ScrollTo` you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms).